# Continuous on a set

Tags: functions, continuity

I am trying to figure out what it means for a function to be continuous on a set. Everything I look up just gives me answers on continuity at a point. I guess I am confused as to what the difference is. Does it have anything to do with LHS and RHS limits?

Comment: well, a set is a particular bunch of points. For instance, $f(x)=x^{-1}$ is continuous at each of $x=3, x=4, x=-10$.

Comment: I have a couple choices to choose from....Could I say then, that a function f: S>R is continuous at the point c in S if for every epsilon>0 there is a delta>0 such that |f(x)-f(c)|< epsilon whenever x in S and |x-c|<delta, if f is continuous at all c in S then f is continuous on the set S? Or would it be continuous on a set if f is continuous at every cluster point of S?

Comment: What you've written is a bit confusing, although I generally like it. When you write the following, it is exactly the definition of continuity at a point: *"a function f: S>R is continuous at the point c in S if for every epsilon>0 there is a delta>0 such that |f(x)-f(c)|< epsilon whenever x in S and |x-c|<delta"*

Comment: *" if f is continuous at all c in S, then f is continuous on the set S"* also sounds fine

Comment: The cluster point business is a subtler point.... but I wouldn't consider the continuity of $f$ at $t$ unless $t\in S$

Comment: I have narrowed down my choices to those two (which I wrote above; sorry they were confusing, I don't know how to use the code to write the proper way), my book is unclear and never mentions continuous functions on sets. So I have discarded 3 other choices and cannot decide between the two I listed. I would prefer to understand things, rather than have someone just say, yeah the last one works, lol. So I appreciate your feedback. I am just not sure which one works.

Comment: My friend said she thought it was , a function is continuous on a set S if the left limit of f is equal to the right limit of f, at every point on S. but I never read anything about limits when reading about continuity.

Comment: There can be more than one definition of the same thing. I would change what your friend said slightly, because I worry about this: let $S=\mathbb{R}$. Consider this discontinuous function: $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} |x| \quad\quad\,\text{if}\quad\quad  |x|>0, \\
      -3 \quad\quad\text{if}\quad\quad  x=0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Then I think my original choice is the best choice

Answer (score 4):

A function is continuous at a set if it is continuous at every point of it.

Ex:
$f$ is continuous at $A$ if $f$ is continuous at every $a\in A$